# "Web services" menu is missing

Tags: magento-1.8, web-services, adminmenu, magento-1.8.1.0

I faced a problem with the menu item "Web services". I tried to add a 3d party module, but I couldn't do that because in my admin menu System I couldn't find the "Web services" menu item.
I already check all models, controllers, and config XML files. All the same as in default Magento installation. I have not any modules that can impact on that menu. Also, SOAP installed and enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed this problem.

1. Got to the  "app\etc\modules"
2. Find files Mage_Api.xml   Mage_Api2.xml    Mage_Oauth.xml
3. In these files, you need to change false to true
4. rebuild Magento cache